# android:Can I read an xhtml file with xmlparser?

Tags: android, file, xhtml, xml-parsing

I need to read an XHTML file with an Android app. How can I do it? Should I use xmlparser, like an xml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A well-formed xhtml document is itself an xml document, so the answer is yes.